# Read lines from a txt file and add and average them

Tags: java, input, sum, output, average

So basically I have to write a txt file with numbers like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And then take each of those and add them to each other to get a grand total of 55 and then 
average them 55/10 to get my answer.

Well I can easily write the numbers to a txt file using:

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

    outputFile.println("1");
    outputFile.println("2");
    outputFile.println("3");
    outputFile.println("4");
    outputFile.println("5");
    outputFile.println("6");
    outputFile.println("7");
    outputFile.println("8");
    outputFile.println("9");
    outputFile.println("10");
    outputFile.close();
```

but how do I read them back in and convert each of them to a number where the sum of them all is 55? Most attempts of mine just read all of them back in or read them in and end up doing weird calculations like

```
3
5
9
14
20
27
ect.
```

Comment: Start by reading a Java IO tutorial.

Comment: Been there done that thanks and lead to me being here.

Comment: Then you should know how to _read them back in_. Show us your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[]args){
 int total = 0;
 int counter = 0;
 Scanner inFile = null;

 try{
 inFile = new Scanner(new File("fileName.txt"));

 while(inFile.hasNext()){
  total += inFile.nextInt();
  counter++;
 }

}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }


System.out.println("Average: "+total/counter);
}
```

Comment: Feel free to post a detailed answer explaining the entire process.

Comment: Because rather than giving up, skipping it and never learning it, now I can sit here and read this and understand what I've been doing wrong for the past 6 hours.  I do want to know how it's done you know.

Comment: Btw thanks a lot solace it's a huge rarity to get actual help like this.

Comment: You're welcome! I forgot to include the try-catch in the first post. I edited it.

Comment: @Solace: You might want to include the while loop in your try as well. Otherwise you'll risk the chance of getting a NullPointerException in the event of a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @PakkuDon I used to include all my code in the try-catch until my programming teacher took off points for it. I guess it's good habit to include only the line that can cause the exception in the try-catch.

Comment: @Solace You have to include only the code which needs to be here in the `try`, and in that case, if you don't include the `while` in the try, you will have *another* exception when you get a `FileNotFoundException` because `inFile` will be `null`, so the `while` *needs to be* in the `try`.

Comment: I don't think it makes a big difference. If the file isn't found, an exception is already thrown, the null pointer isn't a huge deal. But since it bothers you so much, I will re-edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.io.BufferedReader` for reading files, i.e.

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));`

Have a look at the method `readLine()` in the [BufferedReader API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). For more information read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html).